# How do I place something in the classpath of my Java program?

Tags: java, slf4j

I'm not really sure how classpaths work or even what they are so sorry if this is a dumb question but I was getting an error while using an API, saying that SLF4J failed to laod org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder. I was looking at the SLF4J documentation and it mentioned that if one doesn't really care about this not loading, which I don't (and hopefully neither the API), then "place slf4j-nop.jar on the classpath of your application."

I've only been able to find stuff for how to set the classpath of my OS or something, and I'm not sure that I'd be able to even do that if that IS indeed what I need to do, as it's a dependency installed from gradle from oen of the APIs I'm using.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html):

> The preferred way to specify the class path is by using the `-cp` command line switch. This allows the `CLASSPATH` to be set individually for each application without affecting other applications. *Setting the `CLASSPATH` can be tricky and should be performed with care.*

That is, either:

- Specify the directory where the .jar file is located when you run the program:

```sh
$ java -cp /path/to/slf4j-nop.jar -otherflags /path/to/Class.java
```

- Copy the .jar file to the directory where the file is located (or actually, where you run the `java` command). From the same document:

> The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched.